# Problem testing a Bean with a List property

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Hi guys so here is my project:

Two entities connected with each other over a `@OneToMany` relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Brand {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    @NotNull(message = "Brand can not have empty name.")
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="brand"
    , cascade= {CascadeType.DETACH,
            CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.REFRESH},
    fetch = FetchType.EAGER)    
    @OrderBy("price ASC") // order products by price
    private List<Product> productList;

    // getters and setter following here ...
}

@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    @NotNull(message = "Product can not have empty name.")
    private String name;

    @Column
    private Double price;

    @Column
    private Boolean onSale=false;

    @ManyToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.DETACH,
            CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="brand_id", nullable=false)
    private Brand brand;

 // getters and setter following here ...
}

package com.microservices.product.datatranferobject;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;


@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ProductDTO {

    private Long id;

    private String name;    

    private Double price;   

    @JsonIgnore // omit this property when exposing data over the API
    private Boolean onSale;

    private String event;

    public ProductDTO() {

    }    

    public ProductDTO(Long id, String name, Double price, String event, Boolean onSale) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.event = event;
        this.onSale=onSale;
    }

    public Boolean getOnSale() {
        return onSale;
    }

    public void setOnSale(Boolean onSale) {
        this.onSale = onSale;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getEvent() {
        return onSale?"ON SALE":null;
    }

    public void setEvent(String event) {
        this.event = event;
    }    

}


public class BrandDTO {
    private String name;

    private List<ProductDTO> productList;

    public BrandDTO() {}

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<ProductDTO> getProductList() {
        return productList;
    }

    public void setProductList(List<ProductDTO> productList) {
        this.productList = productList;
    }   
}
```

A simple DAO Class:

```
public interface BrandRepository extends JpaRepository<Brand, Long>{

    List<Brand> findAllByOrderByName();
}
```

A simple service:

```
public interface BrandService {

    List<Brand> getAllBrands(); 
}

@Service
public class BrandServiceImpl implements BrandService {

    @Autowired
    BrandRepository myBrandRepo;

    @Override
    public List<Brand> getAllBrands(){
        return myBrandRepo.findAllByOrderByName();
    }   
}
```

and a controller which maps Products to ProductDTOs usinf my custom programmed Mapper:

```
public class ModelMapper {
    public static BrandDTO makeBrandDTO(Brand myBrand)
    {
        BrandDTO myBrandDTO=new BrandDTO();

        org.modelmapper.ModelMapper myStandardMapper=new org.modelmapper.ModelMapper();

        List<ProductDTO> myProductsList=myBrand.getProductList()
                .stream()
                .map(product->myStandardMapper.map(product, ProductDTO.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        myBrandDTO.setProductList(myProductsList);

        myBrandDTO.setName(myBrand.getName());

        return myBrandDTO;
    }
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("v1/search")
public class BrandController {

    @Autowired
    BrandService myBrandService;

    @GetMapping("/get/products/")
    public Map<String, List<ProductDTO>> getAllProductsMap(){

        List<BrandDTO> myList= myBrandService.getAllBrands()
        .stream().map(brand->ModelMapper.makeBrandDTO(brand))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());      

        Map<String, List<ProductDTO>> myMap=new TreeMap<String, List<ProductDTO>> ();

        myList.forEach(brand->myMap.put(brand.getName(), brand.getProductList()));

        return myMap;
    }

}
```

**ProductDTO is quite the same as Product entity so I will spare the time ans space writing it down.**

So here comes the Problem. I am using Junit to test my Controller having the following class run the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ProductApplication.class,webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ControllerLayerTester {

    private static Log myLogger = LogFactory.getLog(ControllerLayerTester.class);

    private static RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private static HttpHeaders headers;

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void runBeforeAllTestMethods() {

        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    }

    /**
     * simple test to verify the given requirements
     */
    @Test
    public void testBrandListIsOrdered() {

        TreeMap<String, List<ProductDTO>> productList=restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:"+port+"/v1/search/get/products/",TreeMap.class);

        for (List<ProductDTO> myProductList:productList.values()) {

            myProductList.forEach(product->assertTrue(product.getId()!=null));

        }
    }

}
```

And when I run it I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.microservices.product.datatranferobject.ProductDTO
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at com.microservices.product.ControllerLayerTester.testBrandListIsOrdered(ControllerLayerTester.java:81)
```

**Am I doing something wrong here ? Why am I not getting the List filled with my entities but instead filled with LinkedHashMaps? Is there a solution in order to get a List of Products?**

**EDIT:**

I am also providing here my project dependencies and I added on top of my post also the DTOs:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.microservices'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile group: 'org.modelmapper', name: 'modelmapper', version: '2.1.0'
    runtimeOnly('com.h2database:h2')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.15.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '23.5-jre'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.7.0'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.7.0' 
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your ProductDTO (even it is the same) and pom.xml? I am asking because for me that code works

Comment: Hi @Adam I just did, you mean that you tested the same code and no error is thrown at all?

Comment: I have just created a project based on the code you pasted and it is working. In order to be 100% sure we have the same code base can you push your code to github so I can clone it?

Comment: Try changing `TreeMap<String, List<ProductDTO>> productList=restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:"+port+"/v1/search/get/products/",TreeMap.class);` to `TreeMap<String, Object> productList=restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:"+port+"/v1/search/get/products/",TreeMap.class);` At runtime it can't infer that you are expecting a `List<ProductDTO>`. I bet that works. The problem is you want to act like the keys are not important, only the values are. Jackson doesn't know how to do that. So either make a custom deserializer or explicitly type the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that parameterization of `TreeMap<String, List<ProductDTO>>` cannot be inferred from `TreeMap.class` inside `restTemplate.getForObject(...)`

You'll want to use the more generic version:

```
restTemplate.exchange(
    "http://localhost:"+port+"/v1/search/get/products/",
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new HttpEntity<>(null, headers),
    new ParameterizedTypeReference<TreeMap<String, List<ProductDTO>>() {}
)
```